# PHP translates NULL to empty strings in MSSQL stored procedures

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Simplified example
This is in a stored procedure

```
select coalesce('(' + phone + ') ', '(' + number + ') '
from example_table
```

so if phone is not NULL I get back (phone) else I get back (number).

the reason for this is that MSSQL is configured as CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, basically if there is a NULL in the concat everything becomes a NULL.

This works as expected when I run it from a client (SQLPro)

When I call this SP from PHP code I get this () brackets only when the value of phone is NULL and reading around it seems that PHP translates NULL to an empty string.

Does anyone know of a way to get around that? Maybe a configuration in the php.ini that will force PHP to treat NULL values as special value NULL instead of translating them to empty strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the expression to something that doesn't depend on the configuration:

```
select '(' + coalesce(phone, number) + ') '
from example_table;
```

If you have more complex expressions, then you might need to use an explicit `case`:

```
select (case when phone is not null then '(' + phone + ') '
             else '(' + number + ') '
        end)
```

Of course, the first version is simpler, but this might be more generalizable.

Comment: That makes sense. Unfortunately, this was a legacy system that is being migrated to AWS so it would have required to change dozens of stored procs. However, after some further investigation I found out the issue and it turns out PHP had nothing to do with it. It turns out that the new DB had CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL defaulted to on as expected but then the property was overridden by AWS and turned off.